# kwargs в аргументах __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Здраствуйте, когда я создал класс, я проверял можно ли одним словарем задать сразу несколько аргументов экземпляра. Оказалось, что можно:

```
class Test:
    dict_1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = Test.dict_1
```

Тогда я подумал, что можно ли с помощью kwargs задать сколько душе угодно аргументов при создании экземпляров:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__ = kwargs

g = Test({'a': 2})
```

И тут появилась ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\79309\Desktop\ПРОЕКТЫ\практика\hhhhh.py", line 8, in <module>
    g = Test({'a': 2})
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Я сразу отрублю, но я писал не только аргумент а, но и другие, так что я не понимаю в чем проблема, можете помочь пожалуйста((

Comment: `g = Test(a=2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`g = Test({'a': 2})` — при таком вызове вы просто передаете в `__init__` один позиционный аргумент: словарь `{'a': 2}`. Ошибки бы не было, если бы он ожидал этот словарь отдельным позиционным аргументом `__init__(self, dict_)`

А в словарь `**kwargs` собираются все пары именованных аргументов и их значений.

Вызов должен выглядеть так: `Test(a = 1, b = 2)` или `Test(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})`, где `**` распакует переданный словарь в именованные аргументы (которые внутри `__init__` снова запакуются в `kwargs`). Второй вариант может использоваться, если этот словарь хранится в отдельной переменной.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs) # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
        self.__dict__ = kwargs

x = Test(a = 1, b = 2)

dict_ = { 'c': 3, 'd': 4 }
y = Test(**dict_)
```

---

А вот ваш первый пример с присваиванием *заранее созданного* словаря в `__dict__`... Так не надо делать, потому что `__dict__` каждого экземпляра начинает ссылаться на один и тот же словарь `dict_1`. Изменение значения атрибута у любого экземпляра будет приводить к изменению значений у всех:

```
class Test:
    dict_1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = Test.dict_1

one = Test()
two = Test()

one.b = 100

print( one.b ); # 100
print( two.b ); # 100 (упс?!)

print( one.__dict__ is two.__dict__ ); # true
```

При необходимости, это можно сделать `self.__dict__ = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}` так, чтобы при каждом вызове создавался отдельный словарь с этими значениями.